# leaflet remove layer is not working in internet explorer 11 using javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I use below script to update my image dynamically, its working fine in chrome and Edge but in internet explorer new image get added unable to remove old image, no error in console.

In below script its passing this condition `if(oldhandle != null  && map.hasLayer(oldhandle ))`

```
var layerHandle;
var map;

function updateLayer(){
    var bounds=XXX;
    var imageUrl=XXX;
    var oldhandle = layerHandle;         
    layerHandle = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, bounds).on("load",function(){
                    if(oldhandle != null  && map.hasLayer(oldhandle ))
                        map.removeLayer(oldhandle);
                    });
        
    layerHandle.addTo(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, however I resolved my issue like this:

```
var map;

function updateLayer(){
    var bounds=XXX;
    var imageUrl=XXX;
    var imageName="myImage";     
    layerHandle = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, bounds, {className:imageName}).on("load",function(){
                  
                    });
        removeMyLayer(imageName);
    layerHandle.addTo(map);
}

function removeMyLayer(imageName){
     map.eachLayers(function(layer){
      if(layer.options && layer.options.className==imageName){
        map.removeLayer(layer);
     }
   })
}
```